# Displaying summernote text in a html page

Tags: jquery, summernote

After saving the summernote code into my mongoDB, I would like to display it on another page using ejs, but this is what I get displayed inside my div tag:

```
<h1>Summernote Example</h1>
<p>Example <u><b style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">text</b></u></p>
```

Note that all I want is the html to be rendered and shown properly in my HTML page. I have tried to parse the HTML using jquery but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: replace your " with ' in : style=" ... " . before showing your html. and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can appear as this:

```
"<h1>Summernote Example</h1>
<p>Example 
<u><b style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>text</b></u>
</p>"
```

The changes here are to swap `"` (double quotation) with `'` (single quotation) as seen around your style properties.

Tip: 
You can declare a variable with codes in two manners:

1) `var htmlCode = '<p id="myobject">This is a Paragraph</p>';` ✔

2) `var htmlCode = "<p id='myobject'>This is a paragraph</p>";` ✔

You cannot however do any of these without getting unexpected results:

1) `var htmlCode = '<p id='myobject'>This is a Paragraph</p>';` ✘

2) `var htmlCode = "<p id="myobject">This is a paragraph</p>";` ✘